# How can I make only the last marker in a KendoUI dataviz line chart visible?

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui, linechart, kendo-dataviz

I tried this:

```
seriesDefaults: {
   type: "line",
   markers: {
      visible: false
   }
},
series: [{
   name:MyLine,
   data:[10,20,30,40,{value: 50, marker: {visible: true, background: "#ababab"}}]
},{
   name:MyOtherLine,
   data:[20,40,60,80,{value: 100, marker: {visible: true, background: "#ff0000"}}]
}],
```

and while it *does* plot the values correctly, the markers don't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a function for the visible setting:

```
markers: {
        visible: function (e) {
           (e.value === 50) ? return true : return false;
        }
}
```

I have found almost anything can be customized in KendoUI using a function.